# How to get the list of files that will be installed when installing a CMake component

Tags: cmake, installation, cpack

Is there any way to know programmatically (in CMake) what files will be installed if a `COMPONENT` is installed (something like a `get_property` of component)?

Currently, I am installing a `COMPONENT` to a temporary location for packaging (not using [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) for packaging) and then packaging using custom commands. I'm invoking the following command during packaging in CMake.

```
cmake -DCOMPONENT=my_test_component 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${TMP_PACKAGING_ROOT}
-P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to get the list of files so that I can only include those files explicitly in the package? Or possibly add them as outputs to the custom command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to know it seems to be by reading the `install_manifest_${component}.txt` which will have all the list of files that will be installed when we install a CMake component.

Comment: I cannot find this file. For which cmake version is this answer?

Comment: ‘cmake -P cmake_install.cmake’ or ‘make install’ will create that file. @ziggystar

Comment: I think it is only created for a component `X`, if you install exactly this component. This means it is not created, if you install all components via e.g. `make install`. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Using ```make install``` will generate a file called ```install_manifest.txt```.

Answer (score 3):

CMake does not have a `get_property()` function (or similar equivalent) for the `COMPONENT` descriptor; CMake properties are reserved for targets, directories, source files, etc. (full list [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html)). However, there are ways to programmatically list the files associated with a `COMPONENT`.

In general, the `COMPONENT` option is often specified with `install()` to essentially categorize targets into specific install groups. These "component" groupings are typically used with [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackComponent.html):

> For certain kinds of binary installers (including the graphical installers on macOS and Windows), CPack generates installers that allow users to select individual application components to install. The contents of each of the components are identified by the `COMPONENT` argument of CMake’s `INSTALL` command.

However, if you're not using CPack, CMake still honors the `COMPONENT` groupings; they are just harder to manage. You can iterate through each install rule in the `cmake_install.cmake` file, and filter out those that pertain a specific `COMPONENT`. This must be done *after* the CMake generate stage (after the `cmake_install.cmake` file is generated), as the full path to each target is not known at configure time. As the question above suggests, you can create a custom target to call the [generated CMake install script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/install.html#generated-installation-script) yourself, filtering based on `COMPONENT`:

```
# Define install rule for MyExecutable target (grouping it in MyComponent).
install(TARGETS MyExecutable
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/installation
    CONFIGURATIONS Release
    COMPONENT MyComponent
)

# Add custom target to filter and install MyComponent files.
add_custom_target(MyInstallTarget
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCOMPONENT=MyComponent -P cmake_install.cmake
    DEPENDS MyExecutable
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

After building this custom target (e.g. `make MyInstallTarget`), the manifest file `install_manifest_MyComponent.txt` will be created, containing a list of all the files associated with that `COMPONENT`. (It is *not* necessarily created by building the CMake-predefined `INSTALL` target.)

However, this manifest file is not very useful by itself. To use it programmatically, we can expand our custom target to read these component-specific files into a CMake variable.

```
add_custom_target(MyInstallTarget
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCOMPONENT=MyComponent -P cmake_install.cmake
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCOMPONENT=MyComponent -P ../my_install_script.cmake
    DEPENDS MyExecutable
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Inside `my_install_script.cmake`, the logic is largely dependent on *what* you want to do with the list of files. The script below will read the files into a CMake list variable, then copies them to an install destination using [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html):

```
# Check if an install COMPONENT was provided.
if(COMPONENT)
    # Read the manifest file.
    file(READ "install_manifest_${COMPONENT}.txt" MY_INSTALL_FILES)
    # Create a list from the component files.
    string(REPLACE "\n" ";" MY_INSTALL_FILES ${MY_INSTALL_FILES})
    # Loop through each file, placing it in the installation directory.
    foreach(curFile ${MY_INSTALL_FILES})
        message("Installing file: " ${curFile})
        configure_file(${curFile} /your/final/install/folder COPYONLY)
    endforeach()
endif(COMPONENT)
```

Comment: Can I somehow install a component group, so that all components within the group have their install manifest written?

Comment: If you want to install multiple `COMPONENT`s, you can add `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCOMPONENT=MyComponent2 -P cmake_install.cmake` to the custom target call, for each different component group you want. You could also expand this to create multiple custom targets for different groupings of `COMPONENT`s. Hopefully that makes sense. If not, I can expand my answer.

Comment: @ziggystar Depending on what custom installation steps you are try to accomplish, I could also see using a bash script (or, say, Python) to read the manifest and do further processing. The fact that you can couple this in the same custom target is the crux of the solution; I just provided a CMake script example to be consistent.